# Proper NSPredicate for Find-or-Create pattern in Core Data

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nspredicate, replace

Below is my **find-or-create** code:

```
+ (id)checkIfEntity:(NSString *)entityName 
        withIDValue:(NSString *)entityIDValue 
           forIDKey:(NSString *)entityIDKey 
    existsInContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{

    // Create fetch request
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];

    // Fetch messages data
    NSEntityDescription *description = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [request setEntity:description];

    // Only include objects that exist (i.e. entityIDKey and entityIDValue's must exist)
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@=%@", entityIDKey, entityIDValue];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];    

    // Execute request that returns array of dashboardEntrys
    NSArray *array = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];

    if ( [array count] ) {

        NSLog(@"%@ = %@ DOES EXIST", entityIDKey, entityIDValue);
        return [array objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@ = %@ DOES NOT EXIST", entityIDKey, entityIDValue);
    return [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:context];
}
```

**Please ignore the fact that I'm not employing best-practices by having two return statements - I will this before pushing my code to production**.

It works by passing an NSManagedObject entity with `entityName`, and has an NSPredicate that checks if there's an `entityIDKey` with value `entityIDValue`; `entityIDKey = entityIDValue`. I've also tried with using `==`.

Regardless which comparison method I use, the `if ( [array count] )` method is never hit, so the second `NSLog` statement always gets output, delineating that an object that I know exists in my Core Data store doesn't actually exist. Therefore, I end up with many duplicate entries when I go to display the contents of my store.

Is my NSPredicate statement correct?

```
    `NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@=%@", entityIDKey, entityIDValue];`
```

where `entityIDKey = @"userID"` and `entityIDvalue = @"1234567890"`

Thanks!

Comment: This method would be incredibly slow and grind your app if you are doing bulk update/creates

Comment: Do you have a better suggestion for implementing Find-Or-Create?

Comment: Also, this will usually be executed in the background on a separate thread. The option will also be available for the user to directly do this, but to avoid so much downtime, I will have it execute every so often in the background

Comment: The problem is if you do this in bulk, the IO involved in hitting the disk for every object will be an absolute killer. The [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003174-SW1) it has a section on `Efficiently Importing Data`. A lot of it is about avoiding unnecessary disk IO

Comment: Thanks for the link! Much obliged!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, the problem was definitely the predicate.

The predicate argument should have been:

`%K == %@`

not

`%@ = %@`